# "No matching ctor found" while trying to populate a Java class from Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I am getting a "No matching ctor found" error while trying to populate a Java class from Clojure.

I want to populate this class from Clojure.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Account {
    Account() { acct_num = 0; 
                trans_type = 'U';
                trans_amt = 0.00;
                cur_bal = 0.00;
                last_update = null;
               }

    public int acct_num = 0;
    public char trans_type;
    public double trans_amt = 0.00;
    public double cur_bal = 0.00;
    public Date last_update;
}
```

I can import the class:

```
ba2-app=> (ns ba2-app (:import Account))
Account
```

but when I go to populate it, I get this error:

```
ba2-app=> (:use java.util.Date)
nil
ba2-app=> (Account. 1000 \C 100.00 0.00 (java.util.Date. "12/21/2011"))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class Account (NO_SOURCE_FILE:9)
```

I followed [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577701/building-java-in-with-clojure-using-cake) to get the Java class built in with my Clojure code. The suggestions which were very helpful, because I can now build the Java class.

Any pointers or suggestions would be helpful. I know the class members should be private, but this is to test out a larger project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the constructor public with the public access modifier. Also your constructor doesn't accept *any* args, but just sets a bunch of members to some values. So you can now actually only call it like: `(Account.)` (if it were public).

When you want to use a constructor like this: `(Account. 1000 \C 100.00 0.00 (java.util.Date. "12/21/2011"))` you'll have to add a constructor that accepts these types of arguments:

```
    public Account(int a, char c, double d1, double d2, Date date) { 
      acct_num = a; 
      trans_type = c;
      trans_amt = d1;
      cur_bal = d2;
      last_update = date;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. public was it along with changing the constructor to populate all fields.

Answer (score 4):

This constructor takes no arguments. You are calling it with lots of arguments. Probably you need to brush up on your Java, or copy some working Java from somewhere else (if your end goal is just to package someone else's Java in your project).

Comment: I've got to post another version, because I noticed that, rebuilt, and get the same error. I'll go edit the question.

Comment: Thanks, and you're right about brushing up. I'm ordering a book. I maintained a Java app years ago. A lot's changed since then.